# Is there a way to disable service account key in GCP for 8hrs or 7 days and then do a delete operation using python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

Code below

```
import requests
import json
import re
import sys
import subprocess
import os
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from google.oauth2 import service_account



credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("")
service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
iam = discovery.build('iam', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
request = service.projects().list()
token1 = subprocess.Popen("gcloud auth print-access-token", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
token, error = token1.communicate()
token = str(token.decode("utf-8"))
token = token.rstrip("\n")
token = token.rstrip("\r")
print(token)


projectid = ""
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
'x-goog-user-project': projectid
}

insights = {}

#https://scalesec.com/blog/identify-unused-service-accounts-in-gcp/
post_url= "https://recommender.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + projectid + "/locations/"+ "global" +"/insightTypes/google.iam.serviceAccount.Insight/insights?filter=insightSubtype=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USAGE"
post_url_data = requests.get(post_url, headers = headers)
get_api_json = json.loads(post_url_data.text)

try:
    for IS in get_api_json["insights"]:
        insightEmail = IS["content"]["email"]
        insightSAID = IS["content"]["serviceAccountId"]
        insightState = IS["description"]
        if("inactive" in insightState):
            insightState = "INACTIVE"
        else:
            insightState = "Active"
        insights[insightSAID] = {"serviceAccountId": insightSAID, "email": insightEmail, "desc": insightState}
except Exception as e:
    pass

SARequest = iam.projects().serviceAccounts().list(name='projects/'+str(projectid))
while SARequest is not None:
    try:
        SAResponse = SARequest.execute()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    #print(SAResponse)
    if(SAResponse == {}):
        SARequest = iam.projects().serviceAccounts().list_next(previous_request=SARequest, previous_response=SAResponse)
        continue
    for sa in SAResponse["accounts"]:
        STATE = "ACTIVE"
        if(sa["uniqueId"] is not None):
            try:
                ukeys = iam.projects().serviceAccounts().keys().list(name='projects/' + projectid + '/serviceAccounts/' + sa["uniqueId"], keyTypes="USER_MANAGED").execute()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            try:
                for ukey in ukeys["keys"]:
                    keyname = ukey['name'].split("/")[-1]
                    # print("keyname is {}".format(keyname))
                    CurrentDate = datetime.now()
                    startdate = CurrentDate - timedelta(days=90)
                    starttime = startdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
                    endtime = CurrentDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
                    validFrom = ukey['validAfterTime']
                    validUntil = ukey['validBeforeTime']
                    validFromDateTimeObject = datetime.strptime(validFrom, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
                    validUntil90DaysDateTimeObject = validFromDateTimeObject + timedelta(days=90)
                    validUntilDateTimeObject = datetime.strptime(validUntil, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
                    korigin = ukey['keyOrigin']
                    ktype = ukey['keyType']
                    #status = ukey['disabled']
                    expired = False
                    compliant = True
                    SAName = sa["name"]
                    if (CurrentDate > validUntilDateTimeObject):
                        expired = True
                    if (CurrentDate > validUntil90DaysDateTimeObject):
                        compliant = False
                    if (CurrentDate > validUntilDateTimeObject) and (CurrentDate > validUntil90DaysDateTimeObject):
                        complaint = False
                    #print(f"{projectid},{SAName},{keyname},{validFrom},{validUntil},{korigin},{ktype},{expired},{compliant}")
                    try:
                        STATE = insights[sa["uniqueId"]]["desc"]
                    except KeyError as e:
                        print(e)
                    try:
                        ts_url= "https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/{}/timeSeries?filter=metric.type%3D%22iam.googleapis.com%2Fservice_account%2Fkey%2Fauthn_events_count%22%20AND%20metric.labels.key_id%3D%22{}%22&interval.endTime={}&interval.startTime={}".format(projectid, keyname, endtime, starttime)
                        ts_url_data = requests.get(ts_url, headers = headers)
                        ts_api_json = json.loads(ts_url_data.text)
                        lastusagetime = ts_api_json["timeSeries"][0]["points"][0]["interval"]["endTime"]
                        print(lastusagetime)
                        if len(ts_api_json["timeSeries"]) > 0:
                            usedin90days = True
                    except Exception as e:
                        lastusagetime = "No Activity"
                        usedin90days = "False"

                    if lastusagetime == "No Activity":
                        print(keyname)
                        disablekeyurl = "https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{}/serviceAccounts/{}/keys/{}:disable".format(projectid, SAName.split("/")[3], keyname)
                        disableresponse = requests.post(disablekeyurl, headers = headers)
                        print(disableresponse)
                        deleteurl = "https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{}/serviceAccounts/{}/keys/{}".format(projectid, SAName.split("/")[3], keyname)
                        deleteresponse = requests.delete(deleteurl, headers = headers)
                        print(deleteresponse)
            except Exception as e:
                pass
        SARequest = iam.projects().serviceAccounts().list_next(previous_request=SARequest, previous_response=SAResponse)
```

The code above list the service accounts and the associated keys, also checks the activity of the keys for last 90 days, if there is a key with no activity within last 90 days, then it disables and then deletes the service account key.

But, what I am looking for is to disable a key for certain (hrs or certain days) and then do a delete operation. Can someone help me on how to achieve that??

Answer (score 1):

The API supports enabling and disabling service account keys. There is no API that accepts a time parameter to then delete the service account key. You must implement that logic yourself.

Note: I do not recommend your strategy of deleting service account keys via automation. There are service accounts that must be enabled for services to function. Create a report on key activity, but require a human to review and approve before deleting a key. Also, note that there is a difference between a service account and a service account key. All service accounts have a Google Managed key that you do not see in the API or Console GUI. Make sure you understand the low level implications of service account key management.

Comment: But, I am only grabbing the user managed service account keys not the google managed ones

Comment: @gcp_user - I answered your question and then offered you some advice. As I mentioned in my answer make sure you understand the low-level details otherwise you might need to engage Google Cloud Support to fix what you break.